# Youtube Video orientation inside uiwebview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, youtube

I have a portrait only app, which is working fine.
I have a news table view and tapping on the news, a new view with a full UIWebView in it (again, portrait only) will show up, if there is a youtube embed inside this view and the user play it, it will play on portrait only.
Is there any way (and i've searched a bit already), to make this youtube player on landscape?

Here you can see the problem, the youtube player with the video only on portrait, and if i turn the iphone to landscape, it still like that, it won't move at all:
[image: yt player]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean a portrait only app - if you've set the project settings to be portrait only (and your delegate rotation methods), then obviously the UIWebView will not rotate.

Comment: I know @Ohnomycoco i am just wondering if there is any way of keeping the app portrait only but to allow the youtube player to be on landscape mode.

Comment: Are you setting the shouldAutorotate delegate to allow rotation in the UIWebView ?